# How to solve RAM issues in R in Windows 11

Tags: r, windows, ram, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 computer. I am trying to build a model in R which is pretty large, and every time R consumes all the RAM memory available, the laptop crashes and I get a Windows blue screen saying that I need to restart it.

In Windows 10 this did not happen. If R consumed all the RAM memory there, it simply displayed an error message saying that it ran out of memory (unable to allocate vector of size whatever).

Am I the only one facing this issue? Is there some way to avoid Windows crashing?

Comment: You should definitely *not* get a bluescreen if R consumes all RAM. The bluescreen is caused by some other issue.

Comment: If I build a smaller model, everything works fine. If I try and build a larger model, I get the bluescreen. Prior to this Windows 11 computer I have been using a Windows 10 computer. There, I could run the small model just fine, but in the larger model I got an allocation memory issue. That's why I am saying that I receive the bluescreen when I run out of RAM memory. And also because I can see that as the large model starts to get built, the RAM consumed by R increases until it reaches a value close to my computer limit, and then crashes.